# Can't view cookie in browser after setting session with express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I am setting the session in my express app with express-session

```
const session = require("express-session");

const sessionConfig = {
      secret: "secret",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      },
    };

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
```

And in my browser I can't see any 'connect.sid' cookie.

[image]

---

express version:

```
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

express-session version:

```
"express-session": "^1.17.2"
```

node version:

```
v14.17.6
```

Comment: what is the express version you're using ?

Comment: `"express": "~4.16.1"` - from the package.json file.

Comment: And also add express-session version to the question ?

Comment: Can you share the whole file and node version ?

Comment: How should I share the whole file? there is a proper way or should I just edit the question and add the script?

Comment: yeah just paste it here

Comment: It's too long, can't let me paste it here or add it to my question. Is there any other way to share my file?

Comment: Copy the most related.

Comment: And make sure from chrome site information that cookies are not blocked.

Comment: did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Not yet, I think the problem is somewhere in my files because I tried to open a new project with the same app.js and in this project I had a session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #2**

try using `node v12.16.1`

note-1: Node.js 12 will remain in support until April 2022

note-2: The current LTS is v16.13.0

---

**Solution #1** (didn't work)

Try using last version of express:

```
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

Comment: I installed the last version and still can't see any session cookie.

Comment: Did you run (npm uninstall express) before running (npm install express) ?

Comment: No, I run `npm i express@latest --save` but I tried to uninstall and install now, still can't see any cookie.

Comment: Have you tried node v12.16.1 yet ?

Comment: Yes, still no session cookie.